# Http Pear Request gzip output

Tags: php, http, gzip

Below is my code i want to output of following in gzip so how to send proper header to get gzip output

```php
$file="www.ntravel.ae/ws";
$request='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><requestAuditInfo></requestAuditInfo>';
$req =new HTTP_Request($file);
$req->setMethod(HTTP_REQUEST_METHOD_POST);
$req->addPostData("xml",$request);
$reqTime = time();
$req->sendRequest();
echo $data = $req->getResponseBody();
```

Comment: It's unclear what you really want here: Do you want to compress your *request* or do you wish to receive a compressed *response*?

Comment: I want to send a request to ntravel. if im sending gzip header in request they will gave me request response in gzip format
like we do in curl 


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate'));

Answer (score 0):

From the API it appears you are still using HTTP_Request. This package has seen its last release in **2008** and has long been superseded by [HTTP_Request2](https://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request2). Please update to latter one ASAP.

As for your problem, I think the [`addHeader()`](https://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request/docs/1.4.4/HTTP_Request/HTTP_Request.html#methodaddHeader) method is what you are looking for:

```
$req->addHeader('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate');
```

In HTTP_Request2, this is handled by the [`setHeader()`](https://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request2/docs/2.3.0/HTTP_Request2/HTTP_Request2.html#methodsetHeader) method:

```
$req->setHeader('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate');
```

On a related note, HTTP_Request is requiring a fully specified URL. `www.ntravel.ae/ws` should really read `http://www.ntravel.ae/ws`.

I am also not sure if you really want to send your XML payload like that. It looks to me like you would want to store that in the request body via [`setBody()`](https://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request/docs/1.4.4/HTTP_Request/HTTP_Request.html#methodsetBody) ([[2]](https://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request2/docs/2.3.0/HTTP_Request2/HTTP_Request2.html#methodsetBody)).